# Visual Studio 2013 Setup Failed from VsGraphics Helper Dependencies (Not a cryptographic message)

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Download the Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate package from Microsoft Volume Licensing site; extracted the ISO to a local folder and ran the EXE.

All goes well for a while, until it fails and says "Setup Failed!"

Then it displays the error message...

> ### Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 VsGraphics Helper
>
> Not a cryptographic message or the cryptographic message is not formatted correctly.

See screenshot @ https://i.stack.imgur.com/stdYB.png

Comment: I've tried this on three different Windows 7 machines; two physical and one virtual.. all failed with the same error type.  So I'm downloading Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, and Windows 8.1 Enterprise now.. will see if it 2012 works any better; and will install 8.1 on VMWare and ten try VS2013 again.

Comment: Looks like **Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate** installed fine on _Windows 7_, unlike **VS2013 Ultimate**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for my issue was to browse the image and locate the installer package for the `vsgraphics_helperbits.msi`.

Location relative to ISO:

`\Install\packages\vsgraphics_helper\amd64\vsgraphics_helperbits.msi`

Answer (score 1):

Just on internet on your pc and go to the below path then rename the amd64 to amd64888s
packages\vsgraphics_helper\amd64

Now run the setup and after getting package error just click on the download from internet option and continue the setup.

Have a happy coding

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem with the `Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate With Update 5` ISO after extracting it even if the SHA-1 was correct.

**Solution if your machine has access to internet** : Simply delete the corrupted packages folders in `packages\`. The installer will prompt you to download them.

You can find the packages in error in the `log` given by the installer when the setup is complete (fail or success).

On my Windows 7, I had to delete these packages to avoid errors and warnings :

- netfx_451mtpack
- netfx_451mtpackcor
- PerfTools_CORE
- PortableLibrary
- **professionalcore**
- sptoolsDependencie
- TFSObjectModel
- TFSStoryboarding
- VCDesigntime
- vcRedistD11
- vc_libraryDesktop
- **vsgraphics_helper**

In bold the critical ones.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue.  Someone at another site suggested that it the ISO image file of the install was corrupt.  We redownloaded it, and it installed correctly the second time.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have updated your windows. (Restart windows after update)
If you have the ISO then mount it to virtual drive and then run the installer. (Don't extract and run)

Hope above instructions will help.

Note: Follow same process for VS 2015 installation.